# Node csv call hangs after completing Mongo write

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I'm using Node to load a CSV file then write it to a MongoDB database. It's actually working, but the script isn't exiting! Here's the core:

```
function commute_process(csvstr, col_commute) {
    csv()
    .from(csvstr, {columns: true})
    .transform(function(row) {
        // unimportant stuff
        return row;
    })
    .on('record', function(row) {
        cleanedrow = // unimportant
        console.log(cleanedrow);
        col_commute.insert(cleanedrow, {w:1}, function(err, result) { assert.equal(null, err); });
    })
    .on('end', function(count){
      console.log('Number of lines: '+count);
    });

    console.log("end of commute_process()")
};
```

`csvstr` is a big string. `col_commute` is a Mongo collection. The logs for each row output normally. The `end` log happens as expected (5000 lines). The database has the correct data. And... that's it. The "end of commute_process()" line does not happen.

Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a callback to close the Mongo connection. So:

```
commute_process(body, col_commute, function() {db.close();});
```

Then, in that function:

```
.on('end', function(count){
  console.log('Number of lines: '+count);
  cb();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the mongo connection remains open likely. Just fire the close method of the connection instance inside the end event. Then, if it still doesn't close run process.exit()

Comment: This almost works, but not quite. Because so much is async, I had to use a callback. See my answer...